# Error while instantiation of sirius elements

Tags: xtext, eclipse-sirius

In sirius I can instantiate elements, the error is when I create a  table, when I give the name 'tache' to this table, the following error occurs 'mismatched character' a 'expecting' w '' And when I change the 't' no error.... I did not understand why the error, the problem is in Letter 't'.
thank you for helping me to solve it.

here is grammar :

```
 Table returns TableDefinition: 
'Table' name=ID  ('champ '   ':'   champ+=[Input](',' champ+=[Input])* ';')'End.'   ;
```

[here is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZpx7.png)

Comment: 'T' instead of 't' also works

Comment: once again posting a MINIMAL but complete reproducing grammar would work. i assume you do some bad stuff regarding keywords/ids. and make sure you have no spaces !!!!!!!!!!! in any keywords.